Stuck in a Memtest64+ loop
I have a Dell XPS and installed Ubuntu on it.
After few weeks it began to run Memtest64+.
In the grub menu I see:

How can I stop my system from running Memtest64 every time I try to boot it and continue to load Ubuntu?

Press E to edit the boot menu, or boot into Ubuntu and set the default os grub will boot in the grub config and run the grub update command
